# Excel Return values from Column A if Column B satisfies if statement Function

Tags: excel

Help in how to do this?

I am new in excel and I wanted to organize the data but I cannot find the right function to make it work.

Need a function to search through Column E for a value and return the texts from Columns A, B, C, D into a new set of columns whenever it strikes a match.

```
A     B     C     D     E
Appl  Text  Text  Text  3
Grap  Text  Text  Text  2
Pear  Text  Text  Text  1
Berr  Text  Text  Text  2
Ora   Text  Text  Text  1
```

For example searching for the value of **3** in Column E and returning the values into something like:

```
A     B     C     D
Appl  Text  Text  Text     
Ban   Text  Text  Text
```

Comment: There is no function to make this work you will need a macro. Can get someone do it for you on http://elance.com or freelancer.com

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=excel+vba+macro+tutorial learn macrtos if you have a narrower question than make this work for me, ask a specific question

Comment: What's the basis for returning `Ban` on the second line of your example results? `vlookup` is the closest function to what you seem to be looking for, but it requires the reference value to be in the first column (and wouldn't produce `ban`, as above).

Answer (score 1):

Can you just **filter** on column E to get all the rows with 3?

For a formula approach, assuming your first table in A1:E5 try this formula in G1

`=IFERROR(INDEX(A$1:A$5,SMALL(IF($E$1:$E$5=3,ROW(A$1:A$5)-ROW(A$1)+1),ROWS(G$1:G1))),"")`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and copied across and down as far as required - once matching rows run out you get blanks

see example [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9qls0kieynyb1vb/multi-lookup.xlsx)

Note: IFERROR requires Excel 2007 or later version, but this can be modified to work with earlier excel versions

Answer (score 0):

The task can be solved with an array formula:

```
{=OFFSET(A$1;SMALL(IF($E$1:$E$5=$B$7;ROW($E$1:$E$5);"");$F8)-1;0)}
```

Press Ctrl-Shift-Enter in a formula window to insert the formula. Curled brackets are inserted by Excel, not by the user. The formula can be copied down and to the right.

To make the task simpler, I added helper cells down from `E8` for listing the occurrences of the desired value.

Rows with the needed value (in `$B$7`) are marked with row number, otherwise with "". `SMALL` takes the n-th smallest value (`$F8` for the row given) used by `OFFSET` to find the needed text.

[image]